# in-app purchase non consumable multiple products iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, in-app-purchase

I want non consumable in-app purchase.

I have some confusion in in-app purchase multiple products **like 110 items price can be variable** then i need to create for all product-id on iTunes ?

Any other way ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes, that is pretty much the way, you are supposed to create 110 product ids for iAP on iTunes.

Comment: @holex thanks for reply.

Comment: @holex suppose i have 54 items to display in tableview in which first 5 are free, other 6 are priced at some $ and all other than that priced at different price, how can i achieve this? i'm so confused where to start and what to do. Please guide me.

Comment: @Nij, you need to configure all 54 items one-by-one on iTunesConnect portal, it does not really matter which price tier you assign to them; the procedure is identical.

Comment: @holex any third party library which serves my need?

Comment: @Nij, yes: your mouse, your keyboard, and your clicking and typing fingers – and _iTunesConnect Portal_ or you can also try the _ApplicationLoader.app_ which is part of the Xcode bundle.

Comment: @holex sorry, i mean not that but any other library like we use AFNetworkinng for web service. Is there anything like that for in-app purchase?

Comment: @Nij, maybe there are 3rd party solutions for that, but it is quite simple to implement `StoreKit`, in my view it is worth to develop your own implementation; it can be faster and more reliable in long term.

Comment: @holex yes i agree with you and already used this approach before in one app. The requirement now is to use 2 in-app purchase (non-consumable) in one view controller for same items. That's why :(